# displaying Google Maps tiles

Tags: android, google-maps, osmdroid

Is it possible to display Google Maps tiles without violating TOS ([https://developers.google.com/android/maps-api-signup](https://developers.google.com/android/maps-api-signup?hl=pl))? I found it http://datamoil.blogspot.com/2011/05/offline-google-maps-on-osmdroid.html but I don't know if I can use it? How can I disable tiles downloading? I'm using really old osmdroid version and I don't have methods like: `setUseDataConnection(true)`, etc...